# Man stranded alone on alien planet with alien machine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi

I read a story in an old scifi mag years back from the 60's or 70's (in Amazing Stories maybe) about a guy stranded alone on an alien planet where there was an intelligent machine that could make things. The only food he had was rotting crumbs from his pocket so all the food that the machine was able to replicate for him only made him sick.

To save his life:

> in the end the machine decided to change him instead, into something it could cater for

brilliant little twist as usual.
That's about all I remember. Does anyone know the name of that story? I would love to track it down again.

Comment: I changed the title to something that's more descriptive, but feel free to change it to something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible you might be referring to A.E. van Vogt's "[Enchanted Village](https://www.librarything.com/topic/69039)", originally published in *Other Worlds Science Stories* in 1950. It does feature a man stranded on an alien planet, and the food provided by the machines does make him sick, as well as eventually transforming him into an alien creature that it could tend to.